# Apply Style for first letter in paragraph only using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have lot of paragraphs in my page

```
<div>
 <p>Sample Text</p>
 <p>Abc</p>
 <p>Third Sample</p>
</div>
```

In each of the paragraph the first letter should be Capitalized and Font-Size is increased via CSS. All the paragraph Content in dynamically loaded. Please suggest me how to solve this without using javascript/jQuery.

Comment: `p::first-letter{...}`?

Comment: as @Vucko suggested also, have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/tL89V/3/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you are

```
p::first-letter
{ 
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 25px; /* Change this to your choice */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Try

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <p>sample Text</p> 
    <p>abc</p> 
    <p>third Sample</p> 
    <p>i think it is working</p>
    <p>isn't it ?</p>

</div>
```

And CSS

```
#mydiv p::first-letter {
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family:arial unicode ms;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#mydiv p {
    color:green;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:arial unicode ms;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CFg72/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

The `::first-letter` selector is used to add a style to the first letter of the specified selector.

Note: The following properties can be used with `::first-letter` :

> font properties
>           color properties 
>           background properties
>           margin properties
>           padding properties
>           border properties
>           text-decoration
>           vertical-align (only if float is 'none')
>           text-transform
>           line-height
>           float
>           clear

Note: The `::first-letter` selector can only be used with block-level elements.

check [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp) for more info and online testing.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing for help on quoting other sources.

Answer (score 0):

```
div >p::first-letter{
   color:red;
   font-size:20pt;
 }
```